# no-use-before-declare is deprecated error

Tags: tslint, angular9

I'm having this TSLint error:

```
no-use-before-declare is deprecated. Since TypeScript 2.9. Please use the built-in compiler checks instead.
```

However, it's on my first line of code:

```
import {Component, OnInit, Input, Output, EventEmitter, OnChanges, SimpleChanges, AfterViewInit} from '@angular/core';
```

Does anyone know why this error pops on this line?

Answer (score 3):

The problem isn't likely with your TypeScript code, but with your `tslint.json` config, that has the entry:

```
{
  rules: {
    ...,
    "no-use-before-declare": true,  
    ...,
  }
}
```

You should delete the entry and you'll be fine.

Comment: This is the information regarding why it was deprecated: https://github.com/palantir/tslint/issues/4100#issuecomment-508539536

Comment: This is the correct answer. Original poster should mark it as such